# Types Vs Methods of authentication

Tags: authentication

As I am very confused, I am not sure how to understand authentication. I am not able to find any book or blog/tutorial that help me understand that, if authentication has types then what are they, and if authentication has methods then how many are they.

I just need a list of types of authentication or methods of authentication ?

I know some types of authentication e.g. Windows(NTML, Kerbrose), Forms(AD, SQL) but then how is it related to classic or **claim base authentication as claim base authentication is not a type of authentication**

**What I exactly need is**

- Types of authentication regardless of Operating system or any other property
- Methods of Authentication (claim based, classic etc..)

Comment: This is probably too broad for StackOverflow and may get closed as off-topic. If you're actually interested in learning this, look up some studying resources for the CISSP exam, that will get you pretty deep into authentication.

Comment: @admdrew sorry but your comment didn't helped, CISSP is a different...

Comment: CISSP is a certification that heavily covers authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

types of authentication

```
a. LDAP "normal LDAP binding", NTLM1/2, Kerberos
b. SQL
```

Regarding methods of authentication i didnt get it because every type of authentication you use differnet method from programing point of view